# Report usage right before billing period ends in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

How can I report how much a customer has used of the service right before the billing period ends in Stripe?

What I found in the docs is that usage can be reported periodically, but in my use case I just want to charge the user in function of how much they used the service. For example if the user has used 900 (arbitrary unit) during the billing period (monthly in my case), then I want to charge them for example 3% of 900 in usd. I can't report usage as it happens because it happens way too often and the sql query to get it is somewhat expensive. But I could at the end of the month get the total usage during that month.

I was thinking I could do this by creating a monthly recurring price for the product with metered usage, and then use a webhook event at the end of the month to report usage. But I'm not sure what webhook event I should be listening to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved this by completely ditching the metered price and creating a normal monthly price for the product with $0/month. I then listen to the `invoice.created` webhook, and I check if the invoice is for this new price, and if so I'd add `invoiceItems` to the invoice with an inline price describing how much the user should pay (which is of course calculated in function of the customer's recorded usage) :

```
$stripe->invoiceItems->create(
    [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'invoice' => $invoiceId,
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'product' => $product,
            'unit_amount_decimal' => $howMuchToPay * 100 //because in cents
        ]
    ]
);
```

This is possible because when the invoice is created, it can still be edited until it's `finalized`.

Comment: Two things for anyone trying to implement this: 

1) If you have a regular (non-metered) subscription price and edit the invoice manually, the timeframe for the 0$ invoice price will be the next billing period (because it calculates upfront) not the last billing period (the period for which we recorded the usage manually). So maybe just use a metered item with a price of 0.

2) You aren't guaranteed to receive the stripe webhook events in the correct order (especially in the time simulation). If you receive invoice.create after the invoice was finalized this setup will fail.

Comment: You're absolutely correct for the first point.  
For the second point, what I found out was that for the second invoice onward this problem doesn't exist because Stripe always keeps the invoice as a draft for one hour before finalising it automatically. For the first invoice however it's not respected if you create a *subscription* directly, but if you create a *subscription schedule* the one hour delay will be applied too. One minor issue to keep in mind is the subscription will be active but your customer won't be charged until the hour passes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collate usage into a single report request, you have up until [5 minutes](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#reporting-usage:%7E:text=Stripe%20leaves%20a%205%20minute%20window%20in%20the%20default%20aggregation%20mode%20(aggregate_usage%3Dsum)%20after%20the%20period%20ends%20to%20allow%20for%20clock%20drift.) *after* the end of the billing period to report usage for that period. Based on that, my recommendation would be to:

1. Listen for [`customer.subscription.updated`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated) events which will fire to [reflect the start of a new billing period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#subscription-events).
2. From receipt of that event, you'll have ~5 minutes to report usage for the **previous** billing period.
3. Collate your usage data from your application using the [`current_period_start`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_start) timestamp from the webhook event, and make the required API request to Stripe reporting the usage.

Comment: Hello Jonathan and thanks a lot for your answer. When reporting the usage, I'm using `current_period_start` as a `timestamp`. However I'm getting this error: `Cannot create the usage record with this timestamp because timestamps must be after the subscription's last invoice period (or current period start time)`. What timestamp should I use?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it's because I used a test clock to test it. NM

Comment: You'd want to instead use the `curent_period_end` timestamp.

Comment: @Johnathan it'd throw an error saying that the timestamp is in the future. So unfortunately I can only use timestamps between current_period_start + 1 and "now", so the 5 minutes thing isn't applied. But maybe that's because I'm using a test clock?